# error trying to download a report with a variable that changes via python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Trying to download a report automatically from our qualys vulnerability scanner, however i'm getting an error due to the variable being an integer and not a string, i understand i need to do str(variable) name, but it doesn't work

newreportID is throwing the error at line 8 with the error above

```
def downloadReport(s, newreportID):
    # ---Download reports---
    payload = {
                'action':'fetch',
                'id': newreportID,
        }
    r = s.post('https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.com:443/api/2.0/fo/report/', data=payload)
    with open("Z:/Shared/Scan_Report_"+ newreportID +".csv", "wb") as report:
        report.write(r.content)

def main(newreportID):
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers.update({'X-Requested-With':'Facklers PyQual python primer'})
    login(s)
    listReports(s, newreportID)
    downloadReport(s, newreportID)
    logout(s)
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__": main(newreportID)
```

Comment: The problem is exactly as the error states. What's wrong with `... + str(newreportID) + ...`?

Comment: when i do that, SyntaxError: can't assign to function call